# Compiling a Derelict program (D)

Tags: compilation, d

I've spent hours trying to do this with no success, so I'm here now.

I'm trying to compile [this (click)](http://bloutiouf.blogspot.com/2011/08/introducing-shaders-in-d.html) program to test my Derelict installation with no success.

I'm using the Arch Linux distribution. I've been trying with multiple command lines and different DMD2 (and GDC) packages from the AUR (community managed repository).
I also tried installing Derelict by either DSSS or from the AUR.

One command line option is:

```
gdc -I/usr/include/d2/ -L -ldl -L -lDerelictGL -L -lDerelictGLUL -L -lDerelictSDL -L -lDerelictUtil *.d -ofexample
```

and another:

```
dmd2 -I/usr/include/d2 main
```

They both throw a plethora of ugly linker errors (different each).

The directories where the supposedly correct files are are:

```
libraries: /usr/lib/libDerelict*.a
"headers": /usr/include/d2/derelict/<folders of modules>
```

I'll be glad to supply you with any kind of additional information.

Thank you,
Nanthiel

**EDIT**

When I run this:

```
dmd -I/usr/include/d2 main.d Display.d -ofexample -L-lDerelictGL -L-lDerelictGLU -L-lDerelictSDL -L-lDerelictUtil -L-ldl
```

it works. However, only with GDC. Not with DMD2. I don't know why.

GDC versions: GCC (4.5.1) gdc (0.30) dmd (2.056)
DMD2 version: I don't know how to get it. :/ But it should be the newest one, as it's from git.

Also, Derelict wants Open GL 3.0 support for custom shaders, when 2.0 should be enough. =/

**EDIT 2**

Here are the linker errors, sorry for the slow update.

```
    dmd -I/usr/include/d2 main.d Display.d -ofexample -L-lDerelictGL -L-lDerelictGLU -L-lDerelictSDL -L-lDerelictUtil -L-ldl
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../libDerelictGL.a(gl.o): In function `_D8derelict6opengl2gl16DerelictGLLoader17getExtensionStateMFAyaZE8derelict6opengl7gltypes16GLExtensionState':
(.text+0x38f9): undefined reference to `_d_throw'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../libDerelictGL.a(gl.o): In function `_D8derelict6opengl2gl16DerelictGLLoader17isExtensionLoadedMFAyaZb':
(.text+0x395d): undefined reference to `_d_throw'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../libDerelictGL.a(gl.o): In function `_D8derelict6opengl2gl16DerelictGLLoader20isExtensionSupportedMFAyaZb':
(.text+0x39c9): undefined reference to `_d_throw'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../libDerelictGL.a(gl.o): In function `_D8derelict6opengl2gl16DerelictGLLoader14loadExtensionsMFZv':
(.text+0x3a6d): undefined reference to `_d_throw'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../libDerelictGL.a(gl.o): In function `_D8derelict6opengl2gl16DerelictGLLoader18loadModernVersionsMFE8derelict6opengl2gl9GLVersionZE8derelict6opengl2gl9GLVersion':
(.text+0x3de0): undefined reference to `_d_throw'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../libDerelictGL.a(gl.o):(.text+0x4889): more undefined references to `_d_throw' follow
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../libDerelictGL.a(extloader.o): In function `_D6object70__T16AssociativeArrayTAyaTE8derelict6opengl7gltypes16GLExtensionStateZ16AssociativeArray3dupMFNdZHAyaE8derelict6opengl7gltypes16GLExtensionState17__foreachbody1277MFKAyaKE8derelict6opengl7gltypes16GLExtensionStateZi':
(.text+0x5b): undefined reference to `_aaGetp'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../libDerelictGL.a(extloader.o): In function `_D8derelict6opengl9extloader23getLoadedExtensionNamesFZAAya':
(.text+0x149): undefined reference to `_aaGetRvaluep'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../libDerelictGL.a(extloader.o): In function `_D8derelict6opengl9extloader23getLoadedExtensionNamesFZAAya':
(.text+0x180): undefined reference to `_d_arrayappendcTp'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../libDerelictGL.a(extloader.o): In function `_D8derelict6opengl9extloader26getNotLoadedExtensionNamesFZAAya':
(.text+0x298): undefined reference to `_d_arrayappendcTp'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../libDerelictGL.a(extloader.o): In function `_D8derelict6opengl9extloader26getNotLoadedExtensionNamesFZAAya':
(.text+0x2ee): undefined reference to `_aaGetRvaluep'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../libDerelictGL.a(extloader.o): In function `_D8derelict6opengl9extloader26getNotLoadedExtensionNamesFZAAya':
(.text+0x35c): undefined reference to `_d_arrayappendcTp'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../libDerelictGL.a(extloader.o): In function `_D8derelict6opengl9extloader11extGetStateFAyaZE8derelict6opengl7gltypes16GLExtensionState':
(.text+0x46f): undefined reference to `_aaInp'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../libDerelictGL.a(extloader.o): In function `_D8derelict6opengl9extloader13extLoadCommonFZv':
(.text+0x126f2): undefined reference to `_aaGetp'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../libDerelictGL.a(extloader.o): In function `_D8derelict6opengl9extloader13extLoadCommonFZv':
(.text+0x1272d): undefined reference to `_aaGetp'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../libDerelictGL.a(extloader.o): In function `_D8derelict6opengl9extloader13extLoadCommonFZv':
(.text+0x12780): undefined reference to `_aaGetp'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../libDerelictGL.a(extloader.o): In function `_D8derelict6opengl9extloader13extLoadCommonFZv':
(.text+0x127f4): undefined reference to `_aaGetp'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../libDerelictGL.a(extloader.o): In function `_D8derelict6opengl9extloader13extLoadCommonFZv':
(.text+0x12840): undefined reference to `_aaGetp'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../libDerelictGL.a(extloader.o):(.text+0x1288c): more undefined references to `_aaGetp' follow
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../libDerelictGL.a(extloader.o): In function `_D6object70__T16AssociativeArrayTAyaTE8derelict6opengl7gltypes16GLExtensionStateZ16AssociativeArray3getMFAyaLE8derelict6opengl7gltypes16GLExtensionStateZE8derelict6opengl7gltypes16GLExtensionState':
(.text._D6object70__T16AssociativeArrayTAyaTE8derelict6opengl7gltypes16GLExtensionStateZ16AssociativeArray3getMFAyaLE8derelict6opengl7gltypes16GLExtensionStateZE8derelict6opengl7gltypes16GLExtensionState[_D6object70__T16AssociativeArrayTAyaTE8derelict6opengl7gltypes16GLExtensionStateZ16AssociativeArray3getMFAyaLE8derelict6opengl7gltypes16GLExtensionStateZE8derelict6opengl7gltypes16GLExtensionState]+0x2a): undefined reference to `_aaInp'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../libDerelictUtil.a(exception.o): In function `_D8derelict4util9exception22SharedLibLoadException8throwNewFxAAaxAAaZv':
(.text+0x1fe): undefined reference to `_d_throw'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../libDerelictUtil.a(exception.o): In function `_D8derelict4util9exception28Derelict_HandleMissingSymbolFAyaAyaZv':
(.text+0x4e2): undefined reference to `_d_throw'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../libDerelictUtil.a(sharedlib.o): In function `_D8derelict4util9sharedlib9SharedLib4loadMFAAyaZv':
(.text+0x176): undefined reference to `_d_arrayappendcTp'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../libDerelictUtil.a(sharedlib.o): In function `_D8derelict4util9sharedlib9SharedLib4loadMFAAyaZv':
(.text+0x1d8): undefined reference to `_d_arrayappendcTp'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
--- errorlevel 1
```

**EDIT 3**

I tried re-installing everything (checked Derelict2 out from SVN, reinstalled DMD2, the `dmd2-complete` package from the AUR) and recompiled Derelict2 again this time using DMD2. It worked. And it also all compiles well now! I don't know what was going on.

If anyone could tell me, what is the procedure of marking this as "solved" or something, now?

Thank you,
Nanthiel

Comment: Could you post some of the first linker errors? You may also need to link against libDerelictUtil.a and libDelerlictGL.a (among others)

Comment: I got it to compile now, using `gdmd -I/usr/include/d2 -L-lDerelictGL -L-lDerelictGLU -L-lDerelictSDL -L-lDerelictUtil -L-ldl main.d -ofexample`. Note that it does not work using DMD2, only GDC. I also failed to recompile Derelict2 with DMD2 for some reason, but it works with GDC. Seems that GDC's version is also older, because it doesn't mention `typedef` deprecation (in favour of `alias`). I will investigate the matter further tomorrow, I need to sleep now. Good night!

Comment: I know for a fact that Derelict2 will compile with DMD 2.056 as I do that (on OSX at least).

Comment: Without linker errors we can't be sure what is the reason - we will just guess.

Comment: Nanthiel, I believe you had old version of the library, and it did not have those symbols inside.

Comment: Must have been something like that --- but that's weird, because AFAIK, it got downloaded from GIT and/or SVN by package build scripts. Oh well, I'm just really happy it works now.

Comment: @MatejNanut Please post a brief answer with the details of what you did to resolve the issue and then accept your own answer. This seems to be a common issue when getting started with derelict, so it'll be good for SO to have a posted solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Tim's request, I will describe how to get an example program ([here](http://blog.fedora-fr.org/bioinfornatics/post/D-Programming-with-SDL-and-openGL)) to compile. Note that this applies to the Arch Linux distribution and might not be the same elsewhere, but should be fairly similiar.

Basically, just call `dmd` with `-I/usr/include/d2 -L-lDerelictGL -L-lDerelictGLU -L-lDerelictSDL -L-lDerelictUtil -L-ldl`. Add other Derelict modules as needed (like `-L-lDerelictSDLttf` for `SDL_ttf`).

Note that the example program on the site has a compile error (easy to fix), and for D2 with the Phobos library, you need to replace Tango's `tostringz` module with `std.string` in `Display.d`.

I installed DMD from the default Arch repositories and Derelict from the AUR. Since DMD was added to an official repository, I suspect users will have fewer problems getting everything to work.